# How to get screenshots of the middle of each scene using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

This code makes a screenshot of the first frame of each scene:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vsync 0 -vf select='gt(scene\,0.4)' -f image2 img-%04d.png
```

How to get screenshots of the middle of each scene?

For example: start scene - `1:25`; end scene - `1:31`. How to get a screenshot on `1:28`?

I tried this:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vsync 0 -vf select='(prev_selected_t*gt(scene\,0.4)+t*gt(scene\,0.4))/2' -f image2 img-%04d.png
```

It's doesn't work:(

Answer (score 2):

The select filter evaluates the expression for truth or falsity as it processes each frame. You want frame `n`, a median frame between two scenes. When ffmpeg is processing frame `n`, it does not know when the scene will end.
Your filter, as written, selects scene change frames as per the criteria.

Instead, you need to do one pass to generate a list of scene change timestamps and then use the select filter to extract the median frames.

For the first part, from [here](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2012-November/011101.html):

```
ffprobe -show_frames -of compact=p=0 -f lavfi 
"movie=$F,select=gt(scene\,.4)" | gsed -r 
's/.*pkt_pts_time=([0-9.]{8,})\|.*/\1/' >> scenes-0.4
```

And then,

```
ffmpeg -vsync 0 -f concat -i list.text -vf select=concatdec_select img-%04d.png
```

where list.txt is

```
file 'video.mp4'
inpoint 23.342
outpoint 23.372
file 'video.mp4'
inpoint 57.031
outpoint 57.064  
...
```

where each inpoint is the median value between two data points in the scene change list, and outpoint is greater than each inpoint by just under the duration for one frame. Some trial and error needed here.

Comment: so this won't work for running select from live capture